# react native 0.63 upgrade 29 to 30

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am using react native version 0.63 and while uploading apk on google play store getting this error.

Your app currently targets API level 29 and must target at least API level 30 to ensure that it is built on the latest APIs optimised for security and performance. Change your app's target API level to at least 30

Kindly help on this.

Comment: [Starting in November 2021, app updates will be required to target API level 30 or above and adjust for behavioral changes in Android 11](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk) , 
In your `build.gradle` file update target sdk version from 29 to 30.

Answer (score 3):

Open your build.gradle in android folder

```
compileSdkVersion  = 30
targetSdkVerion = 30
buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
```

From November 2021 apps to be uploaded in playstore need to have target SDK version as 30.